# UIPageViewController spine in corner

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller

Is it possible to make UIPageViewController to turn pages to corner, not to screen edge?

I understand that it is not provided as is, but may be there are some tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to make it each side of the screen or in the middle of the view only

Comment: I wrote that I know it. I'm trying to find some low level solution.

Comment: low level will be most likely rejected